# how do get number separately

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have number from 1 to 100 in column A1 to A100.

I am trying to achieve two results from data.

I want separately 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and another one 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100

Please help me

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but `=A1` dragged down to `=A9` and `=A1*10` to `=A10*10` would give you that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Maybe*, in B1:

```
=1*(LEN(A1)=1)+2*(RIGHT(A1)="0")
```

double-click the fill handle and sort A:B on ColumnB.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit vague.  If you are looking to count by 10s, try adding a `10` in cell `B1` and then adding the formula `=B1+10` in cell `B2`. You can drag that formula down to count by 10s.

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure.  The question is very vague, as shown by the many downvotes it has received.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we want in column B "0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" and in column C "0, 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100", put:

 -  `=MOD(A1,10)` as formula for the cell B1 

 - `=INT(A1/10)*10` as formula for the cell C1

and then copy them to rest of the rows.

Comment: ya it appears from the question, he's looking for the 1's and 10's. let's see

Comment: Thank you so much for your help punts.Return the answer is perfect. Sorry for the trouble I am not explain properly.

Comment: thats ok just accept the answer that resolved your question